# Create a PDF file on the fly and stream it while it is not yet finished?

Tags: php, pdf, stream

We want to merge a lot of PDF files into one big file and send it to the client. However, the resources on our production server are very restricted, so merging all files in memory first and then sending the finished PDF file results in our script being killed because it exhausts its available memory.

The only solution (besides getting a better server, obviously) would be starting to stream the PDF file before it is fully created to bypass the memory limit.

However I wonder if that is even possible. Can PDF files be streamed before they're fully created? Or doesn't the PDF file format allow streaming unfinished files because some headers or whatever have to be set after the full contents are certain?

If it is possible, which PDF library supports creating a file as a stream? Most libraries that I know of (like TCPDF) seem to create the full file in memory and then in the end output this finished result somewhere (i. e. via the `$tcpdf->Output()` method).

Answer (score 1):

The PDF file format is entirely able to be streamed. There's certainly nothing that'll prevent it anyway.

As an example, we recently had a customer that required reading a single page over a HTTP connection to a remote PDF, without downloading or reading the whole PDF. We're able to do this by making many small HTTP requests for specific content within the PDF. We use the trailer at the end of the PDF and the cross reference table to find the required content without having to parse the whole PDF.

If I understand your problem, it looks like your current library you're using loads each PDF in memory before creating or streaming out the merged document.

If we look at this problem a different way, the better solution would be for the PDF library to only take references to the PDFs to be merged, then when the merged PDF is being created or streamed, pull in the content and resources from the PDFs to be merged, as-and-when required.

I'm not sure how many PHP libraries there are that can do this as I'm not too up-to-date with PHP, but I know there are probably a few C/C++ libraries that may be able to do this. I understand PHP can use extensions to call these libraries. Only downside is that they'll likely have commercial licenses.

Disclaimer: I work for the [Mako SDK](https://www.globalgraphics.com/products/mako-sdk) R&D group, hence why I know for sure there are some libraries which will do this. :)